# Override context-param in web.xml in Jboss EAP 6.4 at deployment time

Tags: java, jboss, war, web.xml, jboss-eap-6

**Goal** - deploy project war on Jboss EAP 6.4 with new values provided for context-param parameters in web.xml without editing existing war.

**Current status** -

- war works if i put required web.xml values at the time of build itself. But it fails when I use default web.xml.
- default war works fine on Tomcat 9 as it has "XML Configuration file path" option available on manager console gui to override values of default web.xml.

**My default web.xml** -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<display-name>Myproject Web Service</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>myproject.appserver</param-name>
    <param-value>jbosseap</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>myproject.logpath</param-name>
    <param-value></param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>myproject.dbtype</param-name>
    <param-value></param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.myproject.ApplicationStartListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/pages//404ErrorView.html</location>
</error-page></web-app>
```

**Required values as** -

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>myproject.logpath</param-name>
    <param-value>D:\myproject\vXX\workspace</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>myproject.dbtype</param-name>
    <param-value>MSSQL</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**Troubleshoot** -

- no such way mentioned in Jboss EAP 6.4 official documentation.
- no such option is available in Jboss EAP Admin Console
  (http://localhost:9990/console/App.html#home) like tomcat for
  deployment.
- none of the SO answers for posts with similar issue
  helpful in my case.

Since we are shipping same war to customers so it is decided not to let customers edit the war and deploy.

If overriding at deployment time isnt at all possible then any official doc reference for such limitation would be helpful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jboss EAP does not support context-param replacement like tomcat. But it does support content replacement for deployed WAR. 

Solution - Replace web.xml using `deployment-overlay` command.

[Official documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.4/html-single/administration_and_configuration_guide/index#Deployment_Descriptor_Overrides)

Hence at user end, web.xml template is required and user will have to put values for context-param as per their environment and re-deploy war.

 war and web.xml must be inside \bin. Else  `deployment-overlay` command fails to recognize path.

Command sequence - Using jboss-cli.bat -

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] deploy s1temp/myproj.war
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] deployment-overlay add --name=s1overlay --content=WEB-INF/web.xml=s1temp/web.xml
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] deployment-overlay link --name=s1overlay --deployments=myproj.war --redeploy-affected
```